# Rails 3.2 Updating Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, update-attributes

Here's my problem. If I go to `Projects#edit`, I am unable to change the course it is assigned to. If I attempt to create a new course for it, or choose from an existing one, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Course with ID=23 for Project with ID=62
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:49:in `update'

{...
"project"=>{"title"=>"Sup",
"due_date"=>"2012-01-23",
"course_id"=>"27",                        # THIS IS THE ID OF THE NEW COURSE I WANT
"course_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Calc I",   # THIS IS THE OLD ONE, I don't need this. Why is it passing this?
"number"=>"MATH102",
"user_id"=>"3",
"id"=>"23"},
"description"=>"bla bla bla"},
"commit"=>"Update Project",
"user_id"=>"3",
"id"=>"62"}
```

So I can see that it's trying to pass in the `course_attributes`, but it's not actually setting the new `course_id`. I don't understand why `course_attributes` is being passed, the other form is blank, and the `course_attributes` being passed, are the attributes of the old course. I want to set the course_id to be the `course_id` being passed (27 in this case).

**ProjectsController**

```
def new
  @project  = @user.projects.new
  @courses = @user.courses    # Used to populate the collection_select
  @project.build_course       # I was informed I need to use this to get the form_for to work
end

def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @courses = @user.courses    # Used to populate the collection_select
end

def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @courses = @user.courses

  if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
    flash[:notice] = 'Project was successfully updated.'
    redirect_to user_projects_path(@user)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Line 49 is the call to `update_attributes`.

***Other Information***

**project.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course

attr_accessible :course_id, :course_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :course
```

**course.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :projects
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects
has_many :courses
```

So a project has a course_id in the database. I'm currently creating or choosing an existing course on the fly on the Projects#new page. Here's my form for that. I use a JavaScript toggle to alternate between the collection_select and the two text_fields.

**projects/new.html.haml**

```
= form_for [@user, @project] do |f|
  # This is shown by default
  = f.collection_select :course_id, @courses, :id, :name, { prompt: true }

  .hidden # This is hidden by default and shown using a toggle
    = f.fields_for :course do |builder|
      = builder.text_field :name, class: 'large', placeholder: 'Ex: Calculus I'
      = builder.label :number, 'Number'
      = builder.text_field :number, class: 'new_project_course_number'
      = builder.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
```

Now, if I am on the new project page, and I attach it to a course by choosing an existing course, it will work correctly. The **Project** will be created, and the `course_id` will be set correctly.

If I am on the new project page, and I create a course by using my JavaScript toggle, then filling out the **Course Name** and **Course Number**, and click Create, then it will also work. The Course will be created, and the **Project** will be created with the correct `course_id`.

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I wanted to provide all information I could. Thanks!

***UPDATE 1***

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    collection do
      get 'completed'
      match 'course/:course_number' => 'projects#course', as: 'course'
    end
  end

  resources :courses
end
```

Comment: Just a hint: it's probably better to move problem description to the head of the post, so that the rest is then read in problem's context.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I just kept writing and writing, haha. I moved some of it around. Thanks @Sergio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `Projects#edit` form is similiar to your `Projects#new`

This is creating the `course_attributes` in params

```
  .hidden # This is hidden by default and shown using a toggle
    = f.fields_for :course do |builder|
      = builder.text_field :name, class: 'large', placeholder: 'Ex: Calculus I'
      = builder.label :number, 'Number'
      = builder.text_field :number, class: 'new_project_course_number'
      = builder.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
```

That's because if a `user` has a current course it will create fields for every course.

If you want to be able to build a new course on the fly in `edit` and `new` change this line to:

```
    = f.fields_for :course, @project.build_course(:user => @user) do |builder|
```

This will build a new `course` regardless of whether you're in edit or new. (Also you can remove `@project.build_course` in your controller this way.)

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. It won't let me reward you with your bounty until tomorrow (22 hours from now). I'll be sure to do so :)

Instead of `:user => @user`, I just used `:user_id => @user.id`. But more specifically, it didn't work with the custom setter, I just left it out and it worked by default. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Also, in the event someone comes up with a different way of doing so, the bounty will go to whichever method seems to be the best. But do let me know what you think on why I couldn't use the custom setter. When I tried, it couldn't find Course with course_id of "". The param was blank.

Comment: Yeah, it's because `course_id` is a Database field. I was thinking backwards, Sorry I'll take that out. But I don't know why the param was passed as "" that's kinda odd.

Answer (score 0):

You don't list your routes, but assuming that is setup correctly, then the ProjectsController update should be able to do something like:

```
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
```

Comment: So even if I set an `@course` instance variable, how does that help the `@project.update_attributes` call?